# How capture multiple shots with captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection

Tags: ios8, avfoundation

I'm trying to implement multiple shots in an ios8 app.
I'm using llsimplecamera (https://github.com/omergul123/LLSimpleCamera) that is a wrapper for AvFoundation that work good as I would.
When I push on the shutter button, 'captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection' (a method of an instance of AVCaptureStillImageOutput) is called and all work well and I obtain a photo.
If I try to put 'captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection', to capture multiple shot, in a loop, I get no photo.
I tried to use semaphore technique:

```
    if ([self.captureDevice lockForConfiguration:nil]) {
    if ([self.captureDevice isFocusModeSupported:AVCaptureFocusModeLocked])
        [self.captureDevice setFocusMode:AVCaptureFocusModeLocked];
    if ([self.captureDevice isExposureModeSupported:AVCaptureExposureModeLocked])
        [self.captureDevice setExposureMode:AVCaptureExposureModeLocked];
    if ([self.captureDevice isWhiteBalanceModeSupported:AVCaptureWhiteBalanceModeLocked])
        [self.captureDevice setWhiteBalanceMode:AVCaptureWhiteBalanceModeLocked];
}

AVCaptureConnection *videoConnection = [self captureConnection];
videoConnection.videoOrientation = [self orientationForConnection];

dispatch_semaphore_t sync = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
while(1)
{
    [self.stillImageOutput captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:videoConnection completionHandler: ^(CMSampleBufferRef imageSampleBuffer, NSError *error)
     {

         if (imageSampleBuffer != NULL)
         {
             NSData *imageData = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageSampleBuffer];
             UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
             NSLog(@"image %@",image);
         }
         dispatch_semaphore_signal(sync);
     }];
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(sync, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
}

return nil;
```

but I get no photo.
What am I doing wrong ? 
thanks in advance